# I want upload youtube videos for specific countries only

Tags: video, youtube, country

I want upload youtube video on my channel and want to show the videos only in pakistan with monetization But I check the option edit and see there are no option for block by country. I did alot of research but every one is saying option is there in edit section but i check many times there are nothing.

I am sharing the screenshot as well.

Please help me

Youtube Uploaded Videos Block by Country Issue

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are looking in the right place, but you don't currently have the proper account privileges to do this.

In order to gain the option to 'Block by Country', your videos must be submitted into YouTubes Content ID System. This is something you must qualify for (eligibility here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1311402).

The **Content ID System** is for YouTube accounts that have a high number videos, where their content is all original.

In order to apply for Content ID, go here: https://www.youtube.com/content_id_signup

If approved, you will have the option to Block By Country. Hope this helps